# NSSegmentedCell in NSTableView in Interface Builder

Tags: ruby, interface-builder, nstableview

I am trying to implement an NSSegmentedCell in an NSTableView (I'm using Ruby, though it's not relevant). I am confused as to how to wire the cell - if I add a table to my application, and then drag an NSSegmentedCell into one of the columns, choose "select any," make sure the cell is enabled and then run a simple application that displays a row, the NSSegmentedCell acts like a momentary push in button rather than a segmented control. What is the necessary code to properly wire a NSSegmentedCell so the user can choose any of the segments, and they remain depressed?

Comment: did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: See this answer - it looks right... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273559/nstableview-nssegmentedcontrol-nssegmentswitchtrackingselectany